# Type does not conform protocol

Tags: swift

Why does the swift compiler say this for the attached code?

"Type 'M' does not conform to protocol 'C'"

```
protocol A {}
protocol B: A {}
protocol C {
    func test(x: A)
}
class M: C {
    func test(x: B) {}
}
```

Comment: Because A does not inherit from B, it works the other way around. the protocol C says that test should accept a parameter of A. Whilst A has the same interface as B, it does not extend or inherit B. So M: C's test function requires a param of type A

Comment: All types that implement `B`, also implement `A`, but not other way around, some types, that implement `A`, do not implement `B`. A types that implement C should be able to work with all types that implement `A`.

Comment: Related on swift-users: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20180115/006897.html.

Comment: @MartinR I read the response in that forum, but, to be honest, I don't understand it very well. Can you elaborate the response? Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo Protocol `C` says that `test` can deal with *any* `A` conforming input. But your class `M` says that it can only deal with `B` conforming input (which is a smaller set of values). What if you upcast an instance of `M` to `C` and then called `test(_:)` with an argument that conformed to `A`, but not `B`? You'd be calling `M`'s `test(_:)` method with something that isn't a `B`, which is illegal. Therefore `M` can't conform to `C`.